# Can't Connect to Amazon RDS MySQL Instance from anywhere Except Home

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, networking, firewall, amazon-rds

I am working on a school project in which we need to perform Statistical Analysis in R. For the sake of the project, I have created an Amazon Web Services RDS MySQL instance, that I would like to share with my colleagues.

I have already uploaded the data that we need for our project in the database and can connect to the instance via both the MySQL Client and R ***from home***. However, I cannot connect from either School or any Local Café via either the MySQL Client or any Local Café.

I have configured the Security Group so that anyone can access the database (both Inbound & Outbound). The Port that I use is ***1433***.

Anybody has an idea how I can resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with this Security Group rule: `0.0.0.0/0` ?

Comment: Yes and that does not work... Also, not that I have data that I would like to hide, but I'd like to keep my database somewhat private

Comment: You can try to do `telnet [your-mysql-domain] [port]`. If you can get through, that means there's no a problem with your Security Group rule, but it's something else.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is because of your os firewall. Can you check that by disabling your own firewall?

Comment: Would it `not` work from home if my firewall blocked the connection...? Why would it be different on another network.

Comment: there is such option on windows firewall public and private network settings.

Comment: Awh ok! I will look into it. Thanks!